# linux web job management

Tags: linux, web, jobs

I have several scripts(jobs) that run on a linux system (bash scripts or python scripts). Each script is continuously performing the same task over and over again, with some sleep in between (performing a task, then sleeping for a while, then performing the task again).

I want to have a web interface where I can at least a) start/stop each script and b)see the status of each script.Ideally I can see the log files in the web as well.

Is there a free (open source) tool that does this?

Comment: [**Supervisord**](https://serversforhackers.com/c/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking into [supervisord](/questions/tagged/supervisord).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use cron service instead of using *sleep()* function combined with infinite loop probably.

And... if you want to manage it via Web GUI, here is an example of open-source project that might be useful for you: https://github.com/alseambusher/crontab-ui.